# Django AttributeError: type object 'Rooms' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

When trying to query or adding any data in the modals, I get the error saying `type object 'Rooms' has no attribute 'objects'`. Here's what I have:

Home/models.py:

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    room_name = models.TextField(max_length=40)
```

Home/url.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePage, EnergyGeneration, RoomPage

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePage.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('energy', EnergyGeneration.as_view(), name='energygeneration'),
    path('room/<int:room_no>/', RoomPage.as_view(), name='roompage'),
]
```

MainProjectApp/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .forms import UpdatedLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Home.url')),
    path('accounts/login/', UpdatedLoginView.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Home/views.py:

```
from Home.models import Rooms, Plugs, PlugElectricityConsumption, EnergyGeneration, EnergyMode, Battery, PowerTransaction, PowerGeneration

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rooms = Rooms.objects.all()
        ......
        ......
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Here's a full stacktrace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Uni\Year 3\Professional Development\Esteem_v2\Home\views.py", line 62, in get
    rooms = Rooms.objects.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: type object 'Rooms' has no attribute 'objects'
```

If I try to query these modals from Python console, it works:

```
from Home.models import Rooms
Rooms.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Rooms: Rooms object (1)>]>
```

But in Django it doesn't. I cannot figure out what is going on.

### Edit

Here is the result of print(type(Rooms)) and print(dir(Rooms)):

```
<class 'type'>

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__mod
ule__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_allowed_methods', 'as_view', 'content_type', 'dis
patch', 'extra_context', 'get', 'get_context_data', 'get_template_names', 'http_method_names', 'http_method_not_allowed', 'options', 'render_to_response', 'response_class', 'setup', 'template_engine
', 'template_name']
```

Comment: Post also your imports aka. from something import Rooms , also your models file is misspelled should be named models.py

Comment: Sorry, that was a misspelling when writing it here. Thank you for clarifying it. I have updated the post with the imports in views.py

Comment: please add `print(type(Rooms))` and `print(dir(Rooms))` before getting all objects in your view and show the result

Comment: Hello. I have updated the post with the results as they were too big for this comment.

Comment: Could you check out example below, even though TemplateView extends base.View probably you shouldn't use get() directly but let me know

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are using TemplateView you probably don't want to use get() instead override get_context_data

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['rooms'] = Rooms.objects.all()
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. Just a question, what's the difference between get() and get_context_data()?

Comment: I was blind should get it sooner, sorry xD lack of sleep.
When you are using clasic class based views functions like get() post() etc.. are HTTP methods -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/ 
In this case TemplateView works differently and implements get() in his own fassion so you should look up in documentation when you use particular classes like that
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView